# Use a Jacobian matrix to differentiate between linear and non-linear transormations

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, transformation

When determining whether or not a map/transformation is linear or non-linear, how can the Jacobian matrix be used? A *linear* equation in two variables is one that may be written in the form *y = ax + b*, but how do know if it is *non*-linear?

Comment: You can check if the transform is linear. If $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies $T(ax+by)=aT(x)+bT(y)\ \forall\ x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then the transform $T$ is linear. Otherwise, it is non-linear.

Comment: Here I assumed that you are mapping from one vector space to another, as you didn't specify this information.

Comment: $y=ax+b$ is NOT a linear map unless $b=0$. And notice that the Jacobian matrix is the first-order derivatives in vector calculus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the Jacobian is constant, your function is linear.